# How to prevent deep link loop (opening the mobile app again) from a browser redirect?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, ios-universal-links, android-deep-link

We have a mobile app and a web site. Users get emails with links to the pages in the web site.
We use iOS universal linking and Android app linking to associate the mobile app with the web site.

Lets say the link in the email is https://abc/ticket/1234.
When users tap the link it opens the relevant page in the mobile app. Users can open the same content in the web site by tapping a button in that mobile page. It opens the relevant page in the web site. We do not open the URL https://abc/ticket/1234 directly. That is because user authenticated through an IDP first and then redirected to the correct page. The URL is something like this https://abc.idp?token=xyz&redirect=https://abc/ticket/1234.

Here is the issue.

1. User taps on the link https://abc/ticket/1234 in the email.
2. Mobile app page gets opened.
3. User taps on the button "Open in Portal" in the mobile page.
4. https://abc.idp?token=xyz&redirect=https://abc/ticket/1234 opens in the browser. (This is because user should be authenticated through IDP first.)
5. After few seconds user gets authenticated and browser is redirected to the https://abc/ticket/1234
6. Mobile app is opened again <--- we do not want this. We need to open it in the browser itself.

In short,

We need to tell the OS whether to open the app or the browser from the same link.

We thought of passing an additional parameter with the URL https://abc/ticket/1234?do_not_open_mobile_app=true but it is not possible to use query parameters for URL comparison in apple-app-site-association file. Then we tried enabling deep links for the IDP as well, then it worked fine in Android, but not in iOS.

Greatly appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Any news, did you solve ?